# Passing Data from one View to another (Storyboard, iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

This is what I got so far.
mainview.m

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender(id)sender {
secondView *secView = [segue destinationViewController]
secView.ext = @".com";
}
```

secondView.h

```
@interface secondView : UIViewController {
NSString *ext;
 }
@proper (nonatomic, retain) NSString *ext;
@end
```

secondView.m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
NSString *url = [@"www.google" stringByAppendingFormat:ext]
}
```

And its returning a error saying ext is null... what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to turn ext into a property instead? My understanding is that the "dot" notation essentially turns your code into

```
[secView setExt:@".com"]
```

So turn SecondView.h into

```
@interface secondView : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *ext;

@end
```

And don't forget to @synthesize it in your .m file

Comment: I actually had those lines.. I just forgot to type them here, let me edit!

Answer (score 1):

Check the followings:

1. Make sure `@synthesize ext;` is in SecondView.m
2. In Storyboard, have you linked the segue correctly?
3. In Stodyboard, is the viewController that represetns SecondView defined as a class of SecondView?
4. Make sure that you are calling the SecondView via `prepareForSegue:sender` method (i.e. SecondView doesn't get called by `pushViewController:animated` somewhere else in your code).

Answer (score 1):

Put a breakpoint at the line:

```
secView.ext = @".com";
```

and make sure that the `ext` ivar is properly set after the assignment. If it's not, you might be specifying that the accessors use a different ivar in your `@synthesize` directive for `ext`, or you might have provided a setter `-setExt:` that doesn't properly set the ivar.

If `ext` *is* set properly after the assignment, perhaps you've got two different instances of `secondView`. That used to happen a lot when people used .xib files -- they'd create one view controller in code and have another instance of the same class in their .xib file. I wouldn't expect that to be the case here since you're getting `secView` straight from the segue, but it's worth thinking about.

Comment: I just found the problem.. I had the segue from the mainView pointed to the Tab Bar Controller and not to the Tab1(which is the secondView) That was causing the destinationViewController return something else!

Comment: I guess the solution to that is to destinationController to the type you're expecting. This would have let you know that you weren't casting the correct type.

Answer (score 1):

There are two views: view1 and view2.

- Add view2.h file in view1.h
- init object of view2  and set their variable.